# Error w/ injecting endorsements w/ ledger on zeronet

Tags: baking

Error: "Ledger Application error (sign): Uregistered Status Message" which occurs when attempting to inject endorsements using ledger.

Anyone familiar w/ this problem? Baking and all other wallet functions work just fine. Have the latest firmware/baking version app, etc.

Comment: That error message is unfortunately uninformative. We'll be working to make it more descriptive very soon